# Why capitalize P in "Provided that", when no punctuation precedes it and it's not starting a new paragraph?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

I emboldened and italicized the "Provided that"s. I confirm that Tenancy Agreement has no punctuation before them. Indubitably they're not starting a new paragraph. Why's P capitalized in "Provided that"? Are these typos?

> #### Yield Up the Said Premises and Handover

> 1. To quietly yield up and deliver the said premises together with the
>    furnishings and all fixtures, fittings and additions therein and
>    thereto at the expiration or sooner determination of this Agreement
>    in good, clean and tenantable repair and condition (fair wear and
>    tear excepted) in accordance with its covenants to repair herein
>    contained notwithstanding any rule of law or equity to the contrary
>    PROVIDED THAT all personal properties and effects,
>    alterations, decorations, partitions, fixtures, fittings and additions
>    therein and thereto of the Tenant or occupier of the said premises
>    shall notwithstanding that the Landlord's consent for the same may
>    have been obtained or given or deemed to have been given if so
>    required at the sole discretion of the Landlord be removed by and
>    at the sole cost and expense of the Tenant at the expiration or
>    sooner determination of this Agreement and the Tenant shall make
>    good and repair in a proper and workmanlike manner all damage
>    to the said premises the said building and the Landlord's fixtures
>    and fittings and the furnishings in the said premises caused by such
>    removal and reinstate the whole or part of the said premises to the
>    condition as they were in at the commencement of the said term
>    AND thereupon to surrender to the Landlord or its agent all keys
>    giving access to all parts of the said premises held by the Tenant
>    and at the Tenant's expense to remove from the doors of the said
>    premises and the directory boards of the said building (if any) all
>    lettering and characters and to make good any damage caused by
>    ***such removal Provided that*** if the Tenant fails to remove its
>    personal properties and effects as left in the said premises
>    (hereinafter referred to as "the abandoned items") the Landlord shall be entitled to give notice in writing to the Tenant to demand
>    the Tenant to remove the abandoned items within three (3) days
>    from the date of the said notice, failing which the Landlord shall be
>    entitled to remove the abandoned items from the said premises
>    without incurring any liability whatsoever to the Tenant therefor
>    but at the costs and expenses of the Tenant to be reimbursed by the
>    Tenant to the Landlord forthwith upon demand or to be recovered
>    by the Landlord from the Tenant as a debt hereunder payable
>    AND thereafter the Landlord may by further notice in writing to
>    the Tenant to demand the Tenant to collect the abandoned items in
>    the manner as may be stated in the said notice but upon full
>    payment of the aforesaid costs and expenses and such further or
>    other costs and expenses which may then have been incurred
>    (including but not limited to storage charges or fees) within three
>    (3) days from the date of the said further notice, failing which the
>    Landlord shall be absolutely entitled to dispose of, sell, give away
>    or otherwise deal with the abandoned items as it shall in its sole
>    discretion see fit and the Tenant shall be deemed to have abandoned
>    its right of ownership of the abandoned items and the right to reclaim
>    the same and/or to claim against and recover from the
>    Landlord any proceeds of sale of the abandoned items if sold by or
>    through or by the order of the Landlord and the Tenant shall
>    indemnify and keep the Landlord indemnified fully against all such
>    demand, claim, proceedings and costs made and brought against
>    the Landlord by any third party(ies) in connection with and/or for
>    the re-claim or recovery of the abandoned items or any part(s)
>    thereof or any proceeds from sale of the same or any part(s) thereof.

> #### Breach of Insurance Policy

> 2. Not to do or permit or suffer or cause to be done any act, deed, matter
>    or thing whatsoever whereby the policy or policies of insurance on the
>    said building or the said premises or any part or parts thereof against
>    loss or damage by fire and/or other insurable perils and/or claims by or
>    liabilities to third parties for the time being in force may be rendered
>    void or voidable or whereby the rate of premium thereon may be
>    ***increased Provided that*** if as the result of any act, deed, matter or thing
>    done, permitted, suffered or caused by the Tenant or occupier of the
>    said premises, the premium on any such policy or policies of insurance
>    shall be increased the Landlord shall be entitled without prejudice to
>    any other remedy hereunder to recover from the Tenant the amount of
>    any such increase and the Tenant shall forthwith repay to the Landlord on demand all sums paid by the Landlord by way of increased or
>    additional premium thereon and all expenses incurred by the Landlord
>    in and about any renewal of such policy or policies arising from or
>    rendered necessary by such breach and in the event of the said premises
>    or the said building or any part or parts thereof being damaged or
>    destroyed by fire or other insurable cause at any time and the insurance
>    money under any insurance against fire or other such cause effected
>    thereon being wholly or partially irrecoverable by reason solely or in
>    part of the Tenant's act or default then and in every such case to
>    forthwith pay to the Landlord the whole or (as the case may require) a
>    fair proportion of the cost of completely rebuilding or reinstating the
>    same.

#### EXCEPTIONS AND RESERVATIONS

> 3. (a) The right to remove, cancel, relocate or otherwise change or carry out any alteration
>    or addition or other works to the common areas (including but not limited to
>    entrances, passages, corridors and staircases) and common facilities (including but
>    not limited to lifts, escalators and toilets) of the said building and such other part
>    or parts of the said building ( other than the said premises) from time to time and in
>    such manner as the Landlord may in its absolute discretion deem fit without the
>    same constituting an actual or constructive eviction of the Tenant and without
>    incut1'ing any liability whatsoever to the Tenant therefor. In particular, the
>    Landlord hereby expressly reserves the right at any time and at its sole discretion
>    to renovate or refurbish the commercial/retail accommodation of the said building
>    and to change, alter, amend, vary, add to and relocate the layout of the
>    commercial/retail accommodation including but not limited to the external walls, entrance lobbies, staircases, landings, passages, corridors, toilets, lifts and
>    escalators and to carry out works to effect such renovation, refurbishment, change,
>    alteration, amendment, variation, addition and re-location ***Provided that*** the size of
>    the said premises shall not be affected or reduced in any way ***And Provided further***
>    that the Tenant shall not be entitled to object to the renovation, refurbishment,
>    change, alteration, amendment, variation, addition, re-location or any works
>    thereof and shall have no right of action or claim for compensation whatsoever in
>    connection with any matters arising from this Clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no grammatical reason for the capitalisation of the 'P' in this situation. It is used merely to merely emphasis the following condition(s) or, as you suggest, typos.